# How obtain smooth subpixel animation when animating Width of a TCircle?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

When I animate the Position of a TCircle, the animation is smooth and appears to happen in subpixel increments/decrements. However, when I animate the Width (or/and Height) of a TCircle, the animation progresses in pixel-increments, making it look a lot less smooth.

This is particularly striking when performing a slow animation where the Positions (X and Y), Width, and Height are simultaneously animated, creating a scaling effect. The left and upper part of the circle animate smoothly outward, while the right and bottom parts are jerky.

Can't figure out why this is happening. All suggestions much appreciated.

(btw, this doesn't happen when Scale.X and Scale.Y are animated. Smooth. But I don't want the stroke thickness to scale, hence the use of Width and Height)

(using XE2)

Some TForm code to demonstrate:

```
object Form6: TForm6
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form6'
  ClientHeight = 821
  ClientWidth = 1108
  Visible = False
  StyleLookup = 'backgroundstyle'
  object cirPulse: TCircle
    Position.Point = '(352,192)'
    Width = 200.000000000000000000
    Height = 200.000000000000000000
    Fill.Kind = bkNone
    StrokeThickness = 10.000000000000000000
    object FloatAnimation1: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 50.000000000000000000
      StartFromCurrent = True
      StopValue = 400.000000000000000000
      PropertyName = 'Width'
    end
    object FloatAnimation2: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 50.000000000000000000
      StartFromCurrent = True
      StopValue = 400.000000000000000000
      PropertyName = 'Height'
    end
    object FloatAnimation3: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 50.000000000000000000
      StartFromCurrent = True
      StopValue = 252.000000000000000000
      PropertyName = 'Position.X'
    end
    object FloatAnimation4: TFloatAnimation
      Enabled = True
      Duration = 50.000000000000000000
      StartFromCurrent = True
      StopValue = 92.000000000000000000
      PropertyName = 'Position.Y'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I seem to have solved this issue, as far as I can tell until now, by changing following line in the FMX.Types unit, in

```
function FitRect(var R: TRectF; BoundsRect: TRectF): Single;
```

Change

```
if ratio < 1 then
begin
  R := RectF(0, 0, RectWidth(R), RectHeight(R));
end
else
begin
  R := RectF(0, 0, round(RectWidth(R) / ratio), round(RectHeight(R) / ratio));
end;
```

into

```
if ratio < 1 then
begin
  R := RectF(0, 0, RectWidth(R), RectHeight(R));
end
else
begin
  R := RectF(0, 0, RectWidth(R) / ratio, RectHeight(R) / ratio);
end;
```

Hence, getting rid of the `Round`.

Haven't tested enough to discover side-effects yet.

Comment: You should log a QC report for this and see what they say.

Comment: Of course, that's what I first tried, twice. Twice I got "service not available," when trying to access QC through the IDE client.